# Google Sheets Query Not Loading on Refresh

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a function that works when I paste it in somewhere, but if I refresh the page Sheets will say it's calculating formulates and finish but won't load any results besides the column headers.

I want to know if there is something wrong with my query and/or if there is a more optimized way to write it so that it gives the same result but loads when the page is refreshed.

---

My sheet has phone numbers, their internal extensions, office locations and the caller ID.

I have one function that looks through the phone numbers and tells me what all the duplicates are. This one will work every time.

```
=query(
    query(
        'Extension & DID List'!A1:D57, 
        "select A, count(A) group by A order by count(A) desc",
        1),
    "WHERE Col2 > 1"
)
```

I have a second function that shows me the rows in my sheet where the duplicate numbers were found. This one will work the first time I paste it in, but if I refresh the page it will only load the headers and no results.

```
=query(
    'Extension & DID List'!A1:D57, 
    "select D, C, B, A WHERE A MATCHES '"&JOIN(
        "|", 
        query(
            query(
                'Extension & DID List'!A1:D57, 
                "select A, count(A) group by A order by count(A) desc",
                1
            ),
            "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 > 1"
        )
    )&"' ORDER BY A"
)
```

---

Here is a visual example of what I mean.

| Initial paste (Desired result) | Page refreshed |
| --- | --- |
| [image: initial-paste] | [image: page-refreshed] |

[Here is a link to the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f6hZTPgDnh0mJiFcMhfCg-H0mGKrcobcjqaILn9lyjg/edit?usp=sharing), please feel free to play around with the formulas on the Duplicate Checks page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to concatenate the options in the first query with an array formula instead of using multiple queries.

> =query( 'Extension & DID List'!A1:D, "select D, C, B, A"&IF(A2="",""," where A = "&A2&CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",""," OR A = "&A3:A))))&" order by A")

I think this will take a look shorter to process! I've tried it in Col I and it seems to work just fine!

PS: your query contained A1:D57 as the range, but you may want to leave it open as A1:D ;)

Comment: This definitely works, but one thing it's missing is the sorting by direct # column so it's clear to see what extensions have the same #s. 

Can you add a sort option to this, or explain the different pieces/logic so one unfamiliar may expand upon it? For the time being I hid the D-G columns (in the real sheet) and added a sort function to achieve the desired result, but would generally love to understand this language more as someone coming from SQL! With the added sort option or a breakdown I can accept this as the answer.

Comment: Hello! Just added " order by A" before the last closing parenthesis ;)

Comment: About understanding the language @SaniEvans, I'm honestly not expert nor even from the field. You may read the documentation: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en or more specific about the language https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage . But in my case it's pretty basic the query, it's more about string manipulation: by concatenating that Array formula, I just added repeated times 'where A = ... Or A = ... Or A = ... ..."

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for your answer and your time! Cheers

Comment: Great! I'm glad it was useful!